# Quais são os requisitos básicos para criar um template WordPress?

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-theme

Gostaria de saber, de acordo com a experiência daqueles que já trabalharam com este tema, quais são os requisitos básicos para se criar um template WordPress.

O que evitar e o que valorizar ao trabalhar com eles? Que relação tem com o Bootstrap?

Atualmente entendo apenas de HTML5, CSS, jQuery e design responsivo.

Comment: Acredito que vá encontrar bom [material de estudo aqui](https://roots.io/). Além de ter o próprio [sage](https://github.com/roots/sage) para ser utilizado como base.

Comment: Alem do que você citou que sabe, vai precisar ter um bom conhecimento sobre a linguagem de programação PHP. De uma vasculhada em exemplos de plugins e themes no github.com, vai encontrar muito código fonte para analisar e estudar. Boas fontes de conhecimento de estudo para WordPress: - http://tutsplus.com/ - http://www.pluralsight.com/ - https://www.udemy.com/ De uma boa estudada nos "quickstarts" mais famosos para WordPress abaixo. 1. https://github.com/Automattic/_s 2. https://github.com/roots/sage

Comment: Muito boa pergunta! Básica porém importante, +1. Tentarei fazer uma resposta nos próximos dias.

Comment: A pergunta sobre sites que vendem themes é péssima, no meu entender é coisa pra perguntar pro Google. Não desiste, não, o Stack é o melhor lugar pra ficar bom de serviço :)

Comment: valew brasofilo :)

Comment: Esta pergunta está sendo discutida no Meta: [Abrir questão fechada, id 87148](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/q/4376/201)

Comment: obrigado pela força @brasofilo